# Check multiple values on SQL query

Tags: php, sql

How to check a multiple values on a SQL query?
Code:

```
$value1 = '...';
$value2 = '...';

$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * 
    FROM table
    WHERE entry = :value1;');       

$statement->bindValue(':value1', $value1 , PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Current code checks only the first value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use IN clause:

```
$values = array(1,2,3,4);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM T 
    WHERE id IN (" . str_pad('', count($values)*2-1,'?,') . ")");
$stmt->execute($values);
```

also you can use
`implode(',', array_fill(1, count($values),'?'))`,
`str_repeat('?,',count($values)-1).'?'`

Idea is clear - repeated qustions)

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: but this method will not work, if you want to use named parameters also... You can't mix it.